# Why is my routing suffix not working anymore after MVC upgrade

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

After upgrading MVC2 to MVC5, my routing isn't working anymore :

```
    routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}.aspx/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

If I remove the .aspx, it will works.

How can I make it works with the .aspx suffix ? I can't remove it in production

Comment: Is that MVC project mixed with webforms pages? If it's the case, then `MapPageRoute` must be used instead. Otherwise, you need to return view from controller instead of using `aspx` extension, because controller is a class name (not actual file name).

Comment: There's only Webforms pages. I needed to upgrade MVC because of our migration to VS2017

Comment: If you want to keep Webforms pages as-is, then `routes.MapPageRoute` to ASPX page is your choice. But if all pages are already converted to Razor view, then remove `.aspx` extension because MVC uses controller classes to return view pages and make sure `return View()` is used.

Comment: I can't keep the aspx suffix ??

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot keep that suffix in MVC unless you have legacy ASPX pages to redirect with `MapPageRoute`. In MVC sense, the request is received by controller through URL instead of view page's code behind.

Comment: So how was my previous code working ?